# Javascript: how to parse an array from beginning and end to center?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing

I have found in Stackoverflow the inverse answer: [Process array from the middle out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937707/javascript-process-array-from-the-middle-out):

```
<html>
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript">

var array = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

function PerformCalc(array, startIndex, direction)
{

if (startIndex < 0){ 
    startIndex = 0;
}
else if ( startIndex > array.length){
    startIndex = array.lenght-1;
};

var sorted = [];

var i = startIndex;

if (direction === 'right'){
    var j = i +1;
    while (j < array.length || i >= 0 ){
        if (i >= 0) sorted.push(array[i]);
        if (j < array.length) sorted.push(array[j]);
        i--;
        j++;                
    };
}
else if(direction === 'left'){
    var j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 || i < array.length ){
        if (i < array.length) sorted.push(array[i]);
        if (j >= 0) sorted.push(array[j]);
        i++;
        j--;                
    };
};

sorted =  sorted.toString();
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = sorted ;            
}

</script>
</head>
<body>  

<p></p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="button" name="Calculate" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" onClick="PerformCalc(array, 2, 'left');">
</form>
<p></p>
Counter &nbsp;<div style="border-width:3px; border-style:solid; border-color:#ff9900; height:25px; width:450px;" id="counter">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a similar script but which can do the inverse: parse the array beginning from index 0  then array.length, then index 1, then array.length -1 and  on on up to the center index (or indexes if array.length is even). Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've described your answer in your question.   :D

```
var reverseIndex;
for (i = 0; i < (array.length/2); i++ ) {
    reverseIndex = array.length - (i + 1);

    // . . . Process array[i] . . .

    if (i !== reverseIndex) {
        // . . . Process array[reverseIndex] . . .
    }
}
```

That should do it, if I am understanding your question correctly.

**UPDATE:**

Per your request, a little more information on the solution . . .   :D

First off, since you will be working in two directions on the same array, you will be going through the array twice as fast as normal.  That's were the `array.length/2` comes in . . . that cuts the number of iterations in half.

Second is the `reverseIndex` . . . while `i` counts from the beginning up, `reverseIndex` will count from the end down.  Since JS arrays are 0-based, the length is always one more than the actual array length (e.g., the array `a`, with 2 entries, references them with `a[0]` and `a[1]`).  Because of this, we have to subtract 1 from the length **before** we subtract the current index (or, add one to the current index, as I have done in the code . . . same effect), to get the correct index for the "end" value.  Example:  If you have a 10-element array, here are your index values:

- i = **0** . . . reverseIndex = length - (i + 1) = 10 - (0 + 1) = **9**
- i = **1** . . . reverseIndex = 10 - (1 + 1) = **8**
- i = **2** . . . reverseIndex = 10 - (2 + 1) = **7**
- i = **3** . . . reverseIndex = 10 - (3 + 1) = **6**
- i = **4** . . . reverseIndex = 10 - (4 + 1) = **5**

Even length arrays are easy, an array with 6 elements will run through the loop 3 times . . . `i` = 0, then 1, then 2 . . . and, at the same time, `reverseIndex` = 5, then 4, then 3.

Odd ones are a little trickier though . . . for an array of length 5, half of the length is 2.5, which means that the `for` loop will still loop through 3 times (`i` values of 0, 1, and 2 are all less than 2.5), but `i` equals `2`, `reverseIndex` also equals `2` and you don't want to process that array element twice.

That's were the `if (i !== reverseIndex)` check comes in . . . it checks to see if `i` and `reverseIndex` have the same value (which will only ever happen for the last iteration of odd-length arrays) and, if the aren't it goes ahead and processes the `reverseIndex` element, in addition to the `i` element.

**UPDATE #2:**

The "in-to-out" approach is actually very similar to to the "out-to-in" approach, it's just a question of setting up the parameters in the `for` loop correctly.

To reverse the direction, you would start with your `i` value in the middle.  Since odd-length arrays would cause a `.5` in the starting index, when you split them in half, you need to adjust that value to the correct starting point.

For a 5-element array, the middle element would need to be `a[2]` . . . the easiest way to get that would be to keep the `array.length/2` value (that we used for the other approach) and round down to the nearest integer: `Math.floor(array.length/2)`.  However, that would throw things off a little for the even-length arrays (half of 6, is 3, and if you `floor` that, you still have `3` for the index, not `2`).

So, you have to get a little creative to get to the middle for both even- and odd-length arrays.  The calculation that will do it is: `(Math.ceil(array.length/2) - 1)` . . . take half of the array, round up to the nearest integer, and subtract 1.  For both the, 5- and 6-element arrays, that gives us a starting index of `2`, which is just what we want.

After finding that mid point, you just do the reverse of the other approach . . . subtract 1 from the index with every loop and stop once `i` is no longer greater than or equal to `0`.

So, the code for the inverse would be:

```
var reverseIndex;
for (i = (Math.ceil(array.length/2) - 1); i >= 0 ; i--) {
    reverseIndex = array.length - (i + 1);

    // . . . Process array[i] . . .

    if (i !== reverseIndex) {
        // . . . Process array[reverseIndex] . . .
    }
}
```

These two are similar enough that you can actually combine them into a single function and just pass the direction in as a parameter, but the code would definitely need some tweaking to do that . . . enough that it might not be worth it to combine them.

Comment: Could you elaborate your suggestion? I'm not a very experienced programmer! Thanks

Comment: Added an explanation of the "tricky points".   :D   Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I have testd your solution and works flawlessly. Could you implement the inverse?: beginning from the center and going to ends? Sorry to ask you such a thing, but I've been on this for more than a week... Thank you very much...

Comment: I think you can develop a more compact solution than what I have done at the beginning. Thanks

Comment: Updated with the inverse logic.   :)

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow but I'm sure it will work fine. You cant'n imagine how grateful I am... :-)

Comment: May, many thanks! The big task ahead is to include them in my rather complex script (it calculates and draws SVG shapes patterns online). Thanks again!!!